# How can i start a timer like call log duration when activity start?

Tags: java, android, timer

Let the question is i want to start a timer which is initialize when the activity is brought to front. I have a text view and i want to display a time start  with 00:00 and increase in every tick.
How can i achieve this?
Thank in advance

Comment: you want to display in this from only hour:minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your textview by a Chronometer view, set his format using `setFormat("HH:MM)` and call to `start()` function when the activity is brought to front.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html)

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you....

```
MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.schedule(myTask, 1000, 1000);


class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
  public void run() {
         Message msg = new Message()
         msg.obj = time// pass your incremented time value
         handler.sendMessage(msg);
  }
}


Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // setText(msg)
    }
};
```